Keyboard shortcut for moving windows between monitors?
On windows 10 & 11 (maybe older versions too), you can move windows between monitors by using Win + Shift + Arrow key. On raspberry pi 5 running pi os, This will move the window, but it will not move the window outside of whatever monitor the window was currently on. Is there a way to make a currently selected window move to  another monitor via keyboard shortcut?
it seems like based on this thread, I would have to modify ~/.config/wayfire.ini, assuming that it's possible in wayfire to move a window to another monitor.
also even if it's not possible with a keyboard binding, is there maybe a terminal command I could use?
